# Single item pre-select checkbox after retrieval list from service in angular 2 not working

Tags: angular, typescript

As the title states it seems to be a fairly easy identifiable problem. 
However the problems that have arisen are quite bonkers to me. I could use some assistence.

I have a service which gets a list of banks. I'm using this service in my component. Upon initialization of this component which uses my list I retrieve the list.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.bankService.getBanks().subscribe(
banks => { this.banks = banks.sort((a, b) => BankModel.sort(a, b));
           this.preSelect(banks);
}

private preSelect(banks: any): any
{
   for(var bank of this.banks)
   {
   //bank.selected = false;
    if(bank.title === "testbank")
    {
       bank.selected = true;
    }
   }
}
```

The html.

```
<div *ngFor="let bank of banks; let indx= index">
 <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox">
  <input id="banktitle_{{bank.id}} type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="bank.selected" 
   (ngModelChange)="checkValid()" name="bank.title" [value]="bank.id">
        <span>{{bank.title}}</span></label>
</div>
```

*The need.* I wish to preselect one of the banks I get by preselecting it in my component.

*The problem* When I add the condition to preselect a single bank it fails. 
The crazy part in my opinion is when I remove that condition it has no problem pre-selecting all my banks.

```
for(var bank of this.banks)
   {
       bank.selected = true;
   }
```

What is happening?

**Update:**

As asked in the comments, I've provided my collection

each object contains the following properties

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] 


Object[0]
id:1
selected:true 
title:"testbank"

Object[1]
id:2
selected:false
title:"testbank2"

Object[2]
id:3
selected:false
title:"testbank3"
```

And so on.

Comment: could you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. Very strange.

Comment: Show the array that you get back from the subscribe before running it through your filter function.

Comment: I'm going to do an update.